# Send array with $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, post

I'm trying to execute a `$.post()` function with an array variable that contains the data, but it seams that I'm doing something wrong because it won't go or it's not possible

```
var parameters = [menu_name, file_name, status, access, parent, classes];
console.log(parameters);

$.post('do.php', { OP: 'new_menu', data: parameters }, function(result) {
     console.log(result);
}, 'json'); //Doesn't work
```

Firebug debug: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument

So, which would be the propper way of doing it (if possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with the help of these StackOverflow fellows I managed to make it work just the way I wanted:

```
var parameters = {
       'name': menu_name.val(),
       'file': file_name.val(),
       'status': status.val(),
       'group': group.val(),
       'parent': parent.val(),
       'classes': classes.val()
};

$.post('do.php', { OP: 'new_menu', data: parameters }, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using for such kind of issues always the $.ajax form like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'do.php',
  data: {
      myarray: yourarray
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  traditional: true,
  success: function(data) {
     alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

the traditional is very important by transfering arrays as data.

Comment: hmmm, interesting... but I'm going to search more and see if there's a way of still using `$.post()`

Comment: maybe just try to add "traditional: true" to your options

Answer (score 1):

### Could be the variables in the parameters array

Having ran your code and supplemented the parameters for something like:

`var parameters = ['foo','bar'];`

It seems to work fine. I think the problem must be in the variables that you are passing as part of the array. i.e. are menu_name, file_name, status, access, parent and classes variables all as you expect them to be? e.g. console log them and see what they are coming out as. One might be an object which doesn't convert to json.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `JSON.stringify()`**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
$.post('do.php', {
        OP: 'new_menu',
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
    },
    function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    'json'
);
```

And then, in the server-side use **json_decode()** to convert to a php array.
http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php